# xpath for two attributes

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

I am having trouble with the syntax for an xpath for two attributes on one element.

Here is my code:

```
WebElement dlFileBtn = driver.findElement(
   By.xpath("//*[contains(@href='/file/download/id/" + downloadID + "')]" 
          + "/@*[title()='Download file']"));
```

Here is the HTML for the element:

```
<a title="Download file" alt="Right-click to download. (Hold-click Mac.)" 
   target="dlfile" data-isimage="false" class="download" 
   href="/file/download/id/1169">Download file</a>
```

Since there are two buttons with the same href, I need to query them on ID and title. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you update the question with a bit more details of your usecase and relevant HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first predicate with `contains()` function has an issue.

- `contains()` accepts two parameters. The first parameter is the value to be tested, and the second is the value to search for. It should be `[contains(@href,'/file/download/id/" + downloadID + "')]`
- or you could just test the entire value with `[@href='/file/download/id/" + downloadID + "']`

The last part of your XPath has a couple of problems: `/@*[title()='Download file']`

- `/@*` instead of applying another predicate filter to the matched element, you are selecting all of the matched elements attributes and then
- `[title()='Download file']` is a predicate filter that attempts to select only the attribute(s) that have `title()` equal to "Download file"
- However, there is no `title()` node selector or function to filter those attributes

You could use multiple predicates and adjust that last part of the XPath to:

```
//*[@href='/file/download/id/" + downloadID + "'][@title='Download file']
```

You can combine those predicate filters and test multiple expressions in the same predicate with `and` and `or` operators.

```
//*[@href='/file/download/id/" + downloadID + "' and @title='Download file']
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no ID available on the element which you have provided,

You can locate element by:

```
//a[@title='Download file' and @href='/file/download/id/1169']
```

Target of  tag.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the below options with cssSelector or xpath works for you, just give a try;

```
WebElement ele1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[id='Id goes here'][title='Download file']"));
WebElement ele1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='Id goes here'][@title='Download file']"));
```